Metrizable topologies and metric induced topologies
While reading Fred H. Croom's Textbook on introductory topology, I was tasked to prove that topology is either metrizable or not. I've found a metric that'd induce it however not all the open sets induced in that metric are contained in the topology. Does this imply that the metric induces the topology?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So let's assume that a metric induced a topology, however I'm interested in a particular topology that happened to be a subset of that induced topology by the metric. Is it valid if I say that that metric induced the particular topology? I hope this's clear enough

Let's take for instance this topology, T = {∅, X, {6}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}} on X = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. Could I say that T is induced by the discrete topology in this case?

A metric induces the topology if the open sets in the metric and the open sets in the topology are precisely the same. If we relax that condition to "every open set in the topology is also open in the metric" then every space is "induced" by the discrete metric, which makes the whole notion rather useless.

Much appreciated!
